# jQuery hide/show content

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I don't Know how to hide, and later show content when user click on button(checkbox). I made code but it doesn't work. When I click on checkbox, content won't hide.
I want make when user clicks on checkbox that frist content hides and second shows. And if user clicks again on checkbox that frist content shows and second hides.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#skin_rasa").click(function() {
        if ($('#skin_rasa').css('display') == 'none')
        {
            $("#_hsync_skin_menu_id").hide("slow", function() {
                $("#_hsync_skin_menu_rasa").show("slow");
            });         
        }
        if ($('#skin_rasa').css('display') != 'none')
        {
            $("#_hsync_skin_menu_rasa").hide("slow", function() {
                $("#_hsync_skin_menu_id").show("slow");
            });         
        }
    });
});     
</script>
```

**@EDIT:** I saw where I did mistake. Now it Works but only on 1st click.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#skin_rasa").click(function() {
        if ($('#_hsync_skin_menu_id').css('display') != 'none')
        {
            $("#_hsync_skin_menu_id").hide("slow", function() {
                $("#_hsync_skin_menu_rasa").show("slow");
            });         
        }
        if ($('#_hsync_skin_menu_id').css('display') == 'none')
        {
            $("#_hsync_skin_menu_rasa").hide("slow", function() {
                $("#_hsync_skin_menu_id").show("slow");
            });         
        }
    });
});     
</script>
```

Comment: Just a comment, instead of checking if an object is visible to decide whether to show or hide it, you could use a form of `toggle` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But now I don't Know how to hide second content on second click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use toggle 
 **Updated** :  working example : http://jsfiddle.net/j999y/1725/

```
   <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox">Toggle
   <p id="myContent">
    Here is your content
    </p>
    <p id="anotherContent" >
    Here is another content content
    </p>
```

JS:

```
   $( "#myCheckBox" ).click(function() {    
      $('#myContent').toggle( "slow");
      $('#anotherContent').toggle( "slow");
   });
```

Comment: But I don't Know how to hide second contect when I click again on checkbox



` $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#skin_rasa").click(function() {
   $("#_hsync_skin_menu_id").toggle("slow", function() {
    $("#_hsync_skin_panel").show("slow");
   });   
  });
 });  
 </script> `